# Understanding post_save and m2m_changed signals in Django(2.2)

Tags: django, django-models, signals

I have a notifications model in Django with a ManyToMany field related to Users. The idea I had was that I would assign all users to a notification on its' creation, then individual users who cleared that notification on the frontend would be removed from the M2M relationship on the backend.  Once the notification had no more users within its' M2M field, the instance would delete itself.

Initially, I tried assigning all users to a notification within its' post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def contract_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    from core.api.serializers import NotificationSerializer

    if created:
        users = User.objects.all()
        instance.users.add(*users)
        return
```

Ofcourse the M2M relations I added didn't save which I found from StackOverflow was because "*M2Ms are saved after instances are saved and thus there won't be any record at all of the m2m updates*" and I would have to use the m2m_changed signal instead.  So I added this signal to see what data would come through (I didn't make any changes to the post save signal above):

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Notification.users.through)
def test(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    print(sender)
    print(instance)
    print(action)
    print(reverse)
    print(model)
    print(pk_set)
```

The actions that trigger the m2m_changed signal are pre_remove and post_remove, and the pk_set contains all of my users that I unsuccessfully tried to assign in the post_save signal. So it's like the M2M relationships were saved or at least carried through the instance save method, but Django then removes them? Could anyone explain why this happens so I can better understand what's going on? Because I am confused why Django can't save the M2M relationships in the first place if it has to trigger the remove methods?

Comment: That's weird. It should only give you `pre_add` and `post_add`. Is there nothing customised on the through table? Or anything special you do about handling the m2m relations?

Comment: No my model, serializers, etc for Notifications is standard, I haven't overridden any of the default methods. This happens when I create a new notification through the admin panel.  Anyway I wasn't expecting the m2m_changed signal to be called, cause I read that m2m relationships aren't saved in post_save signals, instead the remove methods are called, as if it is removing the relationships I tried to add in the post_save signal

Comment: Have you tried playing around `Notification` through the shell or anywhere else aside from admin? Could be that admin is doing something extra that we don't expect.